# How to reduce the memory usage of a multiple ASOF JOIN queries?

Tags: sql, clickhouse, clickhouse-client

I have one query that results in ~100 rows. Not really much. This table is called FillsTable.

Then I have mulitple tables SignalTable1,2,3,4,5,6 that have millions of rows.

I want to ASOF JOIN the first table with all Signal tables to get the values of signals "as-of" the time of fills.

I have written the following:

```
SELECT *, Signal1 FROM (
SELECT *, Signal2 FROM (
SELECT *, Signal3 FROM (
SELECT *, Signal4 FROM (
SELECT *, Signal5 FROM (
SELECT *, Signal6 FROM (
   SELECT * FROM TableFills
   WHERE timestamp between 'start_date' and 'end_date'
) AS F ASOF JOIN SignalTable6 AS S USING (name, timestamp) WHERE S.timestamp between 'start_date' and 'end_date'
) AS F ASOF JOIN SignalTable5 AS S USING (name, timestamp) WHERE S.timestamp between 'start_date' and 'end_date'
) AS F ASOF JOIN SignalTable4 AS S USING (name, timestamp) WHERE S.timestamp between 'start_date' and 'end_date'
) AS F ASOF JOIN SignalTable3 AS S USING (name, timestamp) WHERE S.timestamp between 'start_date' and 'end_date'
) AS F ASOF JOIN SignalTable2 AS S USING (name, timestamp) WHERE S.timestamp between 'start_date' and 'end_date'
) AS F ASOF JOIN SignalTable1 AS S USING (name, timestamp) WHERE S.timestamp between 'start_date' and 'end_date'
```

I would expect the memory usage of the query to be pretty small - the "inside" query has only 100 rows, and it is joined with one signal table at a time. However, it looks like clickhouse computes hash tables for right table for each of the signal tables, and I am hitting our 6GB memory limit pretty fast.

I tried also the following pattern:

```
SELECT T1.name, T1.timestamp, T1.signal1, T2.signal2, ...etc...
FROM (
   SELECT * FROM TableFills WHERE timestamp between 'start_date' and 'end_date'
   ASOF JOIN SignalTable1 AS S WHERE S.timestamp between 'start_date' and 'end_date'
) AS T1
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT * FROM TableFills WHERE timestamp between 'start_date' and 'end_date'
   ASOF JOIN SignalTable1 AS S WHERE S.timestamp between 'start_date' and 'end_date'
) AS T2
ON T1.timestamp = T2.timestamp
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT * FROM TableFills WHERE timestamp between 'start_date' and 'end_date'
   ASOF JOIN SignalTable1 AS S WHERE S.timestamp between 'start_date' and 'end_date'
) AS T3
ON T2.timestamp = T3.timestamp
...etc...
```

However it also resulted in high memory usage.

The only solution looks to me is to execute separate 6 queries and join them on the application side. Is there a better way to ASOF JOIN with multiple tables joining with one table at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like clickhouse does not do the optimization where it can apply `WHERE` to the right part of ASOF JOIN. Put WHERE parts *inside* subqueries to be `ASOF JOIN`ed. That way you'll reduce the hash table size.

```
...etc...
SELECT *, Signal6 FROM (
   SELECT * FROM TableFills
   WHERE timestamp between 'start_date' and 'end_date'
) AS F ASOF JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM SignalTable6 AS S
    WHERE S.timestamp between 'start_date' and 'end_date'
) AS S USING (name, timestamp)
...etc...
```